# Upload API for django server

Tags: python, django, cocoa, upload

I'm playing around with putting together a django app to serve my photo collections. I think I have pretty much everything figured out except for how to implement an API that I can use to upload images from my computer automatically from a cocoa program (e.g. an Apple Aperture plug-in) or python script.  Objectives here:

- be able to type in the username and password on my computer, and have the script log in to the server
- submit the files along with a small amount of metadata for each image
- return a unique id for each image uploaded, in case I want to update the file on the server

After a bit of research, this seems like something that the various REST frameworks could help with, although they seem like a bit of a sledgehammer for such a simple problem. Two questions:

- how do I authenticate my user script properly before uploading the files?
- how do I actually upload the files themselves? The client and server REST APIs generally focus on json/xml interactions, and don't seem to help with files.

Any more general guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is something I was thinking of doing for Lightroom on Mac.

Comment: It's conceptually very simple if you remove the REST framework. Just set up a django view, process login data exactly as you would a browser request but perhaps not using form encoding but JSON, or define a field for credentials for every request. How and when you send these credentials is up to you...

To upload the files themselves, encode your files into base64 for transmission. `file.read().encode('base64')` or `import base64 base64.b64encode(str)` then decode them on the server side. `file_data = DATA.decode('base64')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is to have a view protected by [this snippet for basic auth](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/243/) that simply validates a form. the form can validate the metadata, and contain a file upload field that will automatically take care of recieving and storing the file on the server. Then it's just a matter of uploading the data using POST.

e.g.

```
class FileUploadForm(Form)
    title = CharField()
    picture = FileField()

@logged_in_or_basicauth(realm="FileUpload")
def upload_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST"
        data = FileUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if data.is_valid():
            #save out the file to the webserver here
        else:
            raise Exception('Data not valid! did you forget enctype="form/multipart"?')
    else:
       return HttpResponseForbidden("You do not have permission to access this resource")
```

The advantage of this is that you can easily use this view as the target of a webpage as well.

client side:

python: see http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/authentication.shtml for interaction with a basic-auth server.

curl:

```
curl http://name:passwd@domain/upload/ -T uploadablepic.jpg -d title=holiday&date=2012-10-02
```

Comment: Okay, that part's quite straightforward, but what I'm confused about is how to do the client-side part that communicates with that view. Just a few lines of client-side python [preferably] or a curl script would be helpful.

Comment: Glad I could help. Comment back if you get stuck.